# String Alignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application, i'm parsing the xml file to get the properties of the uilabel, like color, text, alignment. In this i can convert the string to UIColor, but i search lots of links to convert the string to UITextAlignment. I didn,t get any proper solutions.

Waiting for a Solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextAlignment is nothing but enum, so whatever text you are getting in response say you are getting left, center or right then you can create same enum as UITextAlignment ie

```
    enum {
        UITextAlignmentLeft = 0,
        UITextAlignmentCenter,
        UITextAlignmentRight,                   
    }

typedef NSTextAlignment UITextAlignment;
```

and use string to get corresponding value and provide to textAlignment.

Note:This in in-built enum you have to create your own enum with left as 0, center as 1 and right as 2.